# Why Typescript Omit/Pick erase Symbols

Tags: typescript, symbols, mapped-types

First I'm pretty new to TS. And trying to work on some [utilities](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@lieene/ts-utility) for my own projects.
But when I work on type mapping. I found that Pick/Omit/Exclude and other typing instructions removes fields with symbol keys. as the code here:

```
    interface T { a: number;[Symbol.iterator](): IterableIterator<number>; }
    type NoA=Omit<T,'a'>;
```

NoA would be a empty type. But I'am expacting a iterator in it.

Why is this happening? And are there any walk around?

for more info, the related codes in my lib is:

```
export type Merg<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends (k: infer I) => void ? I : never;
export type MergO<U extends object> 
  = (U extends object ? (k: U) => void : never) extends 
    (k: infer I) => void ? (I extends object ? I : object) : object;

export type Alter<T extends object, U extends object> 
  = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, keyof U>> & Pick<U, Extract<keyof T, keyof U>>;

export type Extra<T extends object, U extends object> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, keyof U>>;
export type Common<T extends object, U extends object> = Pick<T, Extract<keyof T, keyof U>>;
export type Extend<T extends object, U extends object> = T & Omit<U, keyof T>;
export type Override<T extends object, U extends object> = Omit<T, keyof U> & U;


export type AlterOver<T extends object, U extends object, X extends object> = Alter<T, Extra<U, X>>;
export type ExtendOver<T extends object, U extends object, X extends object> = Extend<T, Extra<U, X>>;
export type OverrideOver<T extends object, U extends object, X extends object> = Override<T, Extra<U, X>>;

export type AlterLike<T extends object, U extends object, X extends object> = Alter<T, Common<U, X>>;
export type ExtendLike<T extends object, U extends object, X extends object> = Extend<T, Common<U, X>>;
export type OverrideLike<T extends object, U extends object, X extends object> = Override<T, Common<U, X>>;
```

based on @hackape's workaround, a new Exclude by type can be:

```
export type Exclude2<T extends object, U extends object> = 
U extends { [Symbol.iterator]: any } ? Omit<T, keyof U>:
T extends { [Symbol.iterator]: infer IT } ? { [Symbol.iterator]: IT } & Omit<T, keyof U> : Omit<T, keyof U>;
```

Comment: It's just well-known symbols that have this issue.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#24622](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24622) (the issue is listed as "fixed" but it's still open; that "fixed" just means that someone has opened a PR to fix it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like @jcalz mentioned in comment, `Symbol.iterator` is treated as "well known symbol" and excluded from resolved mapped types. Currently, typescript sees any expression of the form `Symbol.whatever` as "well known symbol".

Workaround:

```
interface T { b: boolean; a: number; [Symbol.iterator](): IterableIterator<number>; }

type Omit2<T, K extends keyof T> = T extends { [Symbol.iterator]: infer U } ? { [Symbol.iterator]: U } & Omit<T, K> : Omit<T, K>
type NoA = Omit2<T, 'a'>;
```

Comment: Nice workaround.  I imagine it'd be a big headache to keep applying it every time you manipulate a type that *might* have that symbol key, and supporting the dozen-or-so well-known symbols makes it even worse.   I think OP might want to consider going to [#24622](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24622) and giving it a  or expanding upon the use case, if they want to see it actually addressed.

Comment: So we can do this
 `type ItrType<T> = T extends { [Symbol.iterator]: infer U } ? U : never;
type numItr=ItrType<Array<number>>;`
... alike @hackape did.Exclude2 and  Extract2 can be done similarly. But Pick can nerver work as it uses keyof.